# How do I stop Visual C++ from using local machine locale settings in MFC .rc file generation?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, resource-file

When editing a resource in the Visual Studio resource view, I find that a lot of locale specific information is added to generated rc file. The locale information added is specific to whatever locale my machine is running at the time. It appears to be a project specific setting, because I don't have the same issue with other projects in the solution. I've tried setting the Project's culture to Default and English (US) but neither of these settings appear to make any difference.

Other than hand editing the changes away, is there a way to prevent machine specific locale resources being added? What setting have I neglected to set that is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out there was a #ifdef block defining the locale for each resource loacated about halfway down the file. Moving that file to the top and regenerating the .rc file via Visual Studio seemed to do the trick.